# Create captive portal on Raspbian

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi, portal, captivenetwork

I've got some issues with my captive portal.

I want to open a pop-up when anyone try to connect to my Raspberry wifi access point. In order to, I have turn my Rpi into a wifi access point and I have put a LAMP server on my Rpi.

Actually I use DNSMASQ and i change the conf file to :

```
address=/#/10.0.0.1
listen-address=10.0.0.1
dhcp-range=10.0.0.10,10.0.0.50,12h
```

And I change the iptables in order to capture all the connexion :

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1:443
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1:80
```

So when I connect and go on the browser with my phone I'm redirected to the home page of the server => This is what I want, so it's good :) 
But my problem is I want a trigger to open the home page automatically when i connect to the network.

Anyone knows how to do this ?

Another question, when I call "google.fr" in my browser, I'm redirected to my Apache home page, but when I launch a search request in the browser, I've got an error. Anyone knows why ?

Comment: I guess some additional tags would increase your chance of getting an answer, since this problem is not Raspberry Pi specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reaseon why you get an error is either because :

- your server is not setup for https request
- if you request google.com/search?=whatever, /search doesn't exist on your server.

you need to:

- configure your server for https (but it will show a security alert because of bad certificate)
- tell your server to rewrite any "unknown" url to a specific virtual host showing your home page

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial for Ubuntu, is a good follow along for the **Raspberry Pi** if you are using Apache and php in your captive portal setup.
[http://aryo.info/labs/captive-portal-using-php-and-iptables.html (from archive)](http://web.archive.org/web/20140718080413/http://aryo.info:80/labs/captive-portal-using-php-and-iptables.html)